# How to print string into an array after used the isdigit?

Tags: c

I'm very new to isdigit and the string. I really need help from you guys. I want to print string into an array 'food[f]'.But can you guys help me to check where is my problem ? Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char foo[20];
    float price;
    int number=1;
    int f=0,i=0;
    char *food[f];

adding_food :    

    food[f] = (char*)malloc(25);

    printf("Adding food into Menu (0 to Main Menu): ");
    scanf("%s", foo);
    {
        if(isdigit(foo[0])== 0)
        {
            foo[i] = *food[f]; //something wrong here 
        
            printf("Enter price (RM) : ");
            scanf("%f",&price);
        
            printf("\n%-16d%-19s%6.2f\n\n",number,foo,price);
            printf("\n%-16d%-19s%6.2f\n\n",number,food[f],price);
        
            number++;
            i++;
            f++;
        
            goto adding_food;
        }
        else 
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I would like my output be like this

> Adding food into Menu (0 to Main Menu) : **Cake**
>
> Enter price (RM) : **10**
>
> **1**      **Cake**         **10** //foo[0]
>
> **1**      **Cake**         **10** //food[0]

Comment: `char *food[f];` evaluates to `char *food[0];` - a zero size array! Also why are you using `goto` in this code?

Comment: Since that I might be adding more food into the menu, I still have to maintain it to be *f*, in order to add more than one food into menu. Beside, I used `goto` for looping.

Comment: That's not how it works, the array does not magically grow in size just because you modify a variable. And `goto` is a horrible tool for looping. Use actual loops instead. Your compiler should be complaining about most of this code as well, never ignore compiler warnings!

Comment: @UnholySheep I don't really know what should I do next in order to get run the program without error. Can you do a sample solution for me that can enter more than one input (string) ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JeremyWan What do you expect `isdigit` to do?

Comment: @4386427 , enter string to add my food menu, enter 0 to quit. This is the only method I know in order to do the `int` variable and `string` variable at the same time.

Comment: @JeremyWan Ahhh… In that case do: `if(isdigit(foo[0])== 0)` ==> `if(foo[0] == '0')`

Comment: @JeremyWan Why do you try to store something in the array when you never use it?

Comment: @4386427 Actually this is just a small part of my code. Haha

Comment: @JeremyWan Well, it does look like something that belongs inside a function instead of in `main`. Unfortunately it's unclear to me what you are trying to do. Do you want to save the user input in an array for later use?

Comment: @4386427 Yeah indeed. Since that I'm doing a **adding food menu** for now. Later on, I will print all my food in the menu and choose which want I want to purchase by entering the **numbers** . Do you get the picture of what I'm trying to do ? The method I know is saving all these into array then print it out whenever I want to purchase them.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code. Example:

```
char *food[f];
```

is similar to

```
char *food[0];
```

as `f` is zero. That makes no sense.

Also the use of `goto` is not considered good style.

So let me show you another approach. Something like:

```
// Make a type that can hold both a name and a price
struct item  
{
    char name[25];
    float price;
};

#define MAX_ITEMS 100

struct item* addItems(int* n)
{
    *n = 0;
    struct item* items = malloc(MAX_ITEMS * sizeof *items);
    if (items == NULL) return NULL;

    while (*n != MAX_ITEMS)
    {
         scanf("%24s", items[*n].name);
         if (items[*n].name[0] == '0') break;

         scanf("%f", &items[*n].price);

         *n += 1;
    }
    return items;
}

void print_all(struct item* my_items, int num_items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; ++i)
        printf("%s %f\n", my_items[i].name, my_items[i].price);
}

int main()
{
    int num_items;
    struct item* my_items = addItems(&num_items);
    print_all(my_items, num_items);
    free(my_items);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But what if I want to print some selected food, where should I change ? For example, I have **1. cake , 2. bread, 3. tuna  4. cheese.** Then I want to purchase(or print) bread and cheese only. what should I do. (I can't simply make item code 3 as tuna, because tuna is appended.)

so I might want to change sth here. Instead of the `for` loop 
`void print_all(struct item* my_items, int num_items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; ++i)
        printf("%s %f\n", my_items[i].name, my_items[i].price);
}`

Comment: That's the reason why I'm trying to use the array.